# How to solve this bibliography error?

Tags: bibliographies, errors

Here is my bibliography in latex. The types is "Inprooceedings".

I use WinEdt.

```
  @INPROCEEDINGS{tem_1,
  Author         = {Comelli, P, Ferragina, P, Granieri, M.N, and Stabile, F},
  Title          = {Optical recognition of motor vehicle license plates},
  Year           = {1995},
  Volume         = {44},
  Series         = {4),
  Month          = {November},
  Pages          = {790–799},
  Publisher      = {Vehicular Technology, IEEE Transactions}
   }
```

But i get this error.
[image: Error image in latex]

How to solve it?

Comment: The character you are using in `Pages = {790–799}` is not the minus sign `-` but `–` which is U+2013 and it's not recognized as a valid character unless you declare it as such.

Comment: So, how to solve it?

Comment: Use the minus sign `-` instead.

Comment: I have try to edit "Pages = {4506--4510}," / "Pages = {4506$-$4510}" and include the \usepackage{tabularx}. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @karlkoeller - the OP may have become confused by your locution, "use the minus sign `-`", into thinking that he/she should use `$-$` as the separator.

Comment: @Mico You are right, I apologise

Comment: It should be `Comelli, P.` with a final period (unless the author's name is *exactly* “P”). The fact that, with some styles, BibTeX will add the period doesn't change the need for stating in the `.bib` file that we have an abbreviation.

Comment: These brackets are mismatched: `Series         = {4)`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're using a non-ASCII character, `–`, as the symbol to separate the first and last page of the range of pages. (Note the subtle difference between the Unicode endash symbol `–` and the "simple dash" symbol `-`.) I assume that you're using pdfLaTeX rather than either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX; unless you've gone to some trouble to inform pdfLaTeX what it should do with the non-ASCII en-dash character, you'll get an error message such as the one you show in your posting.

There's a separate issue at stake: In some bibliography styles only the first page of a page range is shown. For BibTeX to be able to parse the contents of the `pages` field correctly and to extract just the starting page, it expects that either a single dash or a double dash are used as the range indicator. All other symbols, including the Unicode en-dash character `–`, will make BibTeX fail this task.

You should therefore use either

- a single dash, `-`, or
- a double dash, `--`

as the range indicator in the `pages` field. Do *not* use a Unicode en-dash, `–`, two such characters in a row `––`, a math-minus, `$-$`, or a double Unicode en-dash in math mode, `$––$`. (In your comment to @karlkoeller's suggestion, you report that you've tried `––` and `$–$`, i.e., with the Unicode en-dash character present.)

Incidentally, there's a separate error in the entry you show, in the `author` field. Instead of

```
author = {Comelli, P, Ferragina, P, Granieri, M.N, and Stabile, F},
```

you shoud have

```
author = {Comelli, P. and Ferragina, P. and Granieri, M.N. and Stabile, F.},
```

I.e., remove three commas and insert two `and` terms. Recall that `and` has a reserved meaning in author and editor fields as the separator between authors/editors. By the way, it's a really good idea to provide `.` symbols after abbreviated first and middle names.