# garbled bibtex entry

Tags: bibtex

For the following bibtex entry

```
@Article{REF56,
author = {E Shamonina and L Solymar},
title = {{Magneto-inductive waves supported by metamaterial elements: components for a one-dimensional waveguide}},
journal = {JOURNAL OF PHYSICS D: APPLIED PHYSICS},
year = {2004},
OPTkey = {•},
volume = {37},
number = {3},
pages = {362–367},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```

the output in the generated PDF file is as follows:

```
Shamonina, E. & Solymar, L. (2004), ‘Magneto-inductive waves supported by metamaterial
elements: components for a one-dimensional waveguide’, JOURNAL OF
PHYSICS D: APPLIED PHYSICS 37(3), 362âAS367.
```

It is evident that the page numbers are garbled. Any idea why? I have other similar entries and none of the page numbers are garbled, as in the case of this one. For a MWE, I am using the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

% all packages as necessary

\begin{document}

......

\end{document}
```

P.S The style file I am using is utthesis.sty which can be found at the following link:

[ut-thesis](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/utthesis/utthesis.sty)

Comment: You should use a hyphen, not the UTF-8 character EN DASH as the separator in the `pages` field.

Comment: potential duplicate: [How to solve this bibliography error?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130756/579)

Comment: I could work around the problem by enclosing the - inside {}

Comment: Delete the character and type a hyphen. Or type two hyphens to get the symbol normally used for page ranges.