# No dash between page range in natbib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, sharelatex

The articles and books I reference to in my master's thesis are missing the "-" sign between the page numbers, so instead of "20-22" the result becomes "20 22" in the PDF-file. I use a bibtex database for all my references and `apalike` bibliography style.

My project is written in ShareLatex.

Please see the example below.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{Illy,
    author = {E. Illy},
    title = {{The Complexity of Coffee}},
    journal = {Scientific American},
    month = {June},
    year = {2002},
    pages = {86--91}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Some existing text \citep{Illy}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

% In the reference list the article should be represented like this:
Illy, E. (2002). The Complexity of Coffee. Scientific American, pages 86–91

% BUT the result look like this:
Illy, E. (2002). The Complexity of Coffee. Scientific American, pages 86 91

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What are you using to compile the bibliography ? I just did it with `bibtex` and the result looks good.

Comment: @Nicolas Since I use ShareLatex, I am not completely sure that its going when I compile my document. In the settings window I can choose between pdfLaTex (current), LaTex, XeLaTex, and LuaLaTex.

Comment: Try erasing all temporary files (`.aux,.out,.log` and so on) to prevent any conflicts. Then use `pdflatex` to compile the `.tex` and after `bibtex` to compile the `.aux`. It should work fine.

Comment: @Nicolas It didn't work. I have discovered that the "-" sign properly exists - when I copy the data from the reference list into notepad the "-" exists.

Comment: Yes, you have to be careful when you copy/paste special characters. Make sure the dashes are actual dashes in the `.bib` file and remove the temporary files as I mentioned above. These are often a source of problem !

Comment: when you cut-and-paste, you're almost certainly getting the "wrong" unicode character -- a one-character en-dash.  it's best to replace that in your `.bib` file by a typed-in double hyphen because that's what latex expects.  look at this question: [How to solve this bibliography error?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130766/579)

Comment: Please note that all .bib files should indicate a page range with a single dash, e.g. "12-17", not a double dash. Based on the .bst file in use, the "12-17" will be translated into "12--17", "12-17" (or whatever else the actual journal requires).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file runs properly with me, so there two possible explanations:

- As suggested by @barbara beeton you have problems with the *"dash"* unicode characters, see [related post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130766/579).
- You are not compiling the document correctly. As mentioned in the comments, run:

> pdflatex *file.tex*
>
> bibtex *file.aux*
>
> pdflatex *file.tex*
>
> pdflatex *file.tex*

And the output should look like this:

[image: final output]